# Problem unsetting a session variable

Tags: php, session, session-variables

There's a form on my site that's used for inviting friends. It's a simple text field and a submit button. If there is an error I redirect back to this page and display an error message if their is a session variable set.

```
if (isset($_SESSION['invite_error'])) {
   echo $_SESSION['invite_error'];
   unset($_SESSION['invite_error']);
}
```

However, if I navigate away from this page and come back to it -the error message is still being displayed. If I navigate away and come back one more time it will be done. It's the same when I refresh that page...1 refresh won't get rid of it, but 2 will. I can't destroy the entire session, I just want to unset this one variable. PHP version is 5.2.5 build 6, register globals is off, I'm calling session_start() at the top of this page, I've tried using a no-cache header as well.

Edit: Added full code.

```
<?php 
ob_start();
session_start();

$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$user_name = $_SESSION['user_name'];

if ($user_id==null) header("Location: /login.php");

if (isset($_SESSION['invite_errors'])) {

    $error = $_SESSION['invite_errors'];
    unset($_SESSION['invite_errors']);

}

require_once("ui/header.php");
?>



<div id="invite" class="content">

    <?php if($error) { ?>
        <div class="errors round">
            <?php echo $error ?>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>

    <h3>Invite Your Friends</h3>

    <div class="invite-form">
        <form method="post" action="controllers/invite.php">
            <div class="row">
                <textarea class="txt-area" name="emails" id="emails" rows="5"></textarea>
                <div class="tip">Separate multiple email addresses with ,</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row-submit">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="submit-btn" value="Submit" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

</div>

<?php
    require_once("ui/footer.php");
?>
```

Comment: unset($_SESSION['invite_error']; => unset right ) is not there. I guess it's a copy paste issue.

Comment: Are you using AJAX anywhere in the requests?

Comment: Could the error be in another variable, which is being set before you unset the $_SESSION var ?

Comment: When you say "come back to it", are you using the Back button, or clicking on the page link again?

Comment: @Razzed I'm not using the back button. Using the Home link and then the Invite Friends link to go back to the page.

Comment: @irrelevant
You should probably use a querystring.

Comment: Try posting some more code to see if we can spot anything.

Comment: It may be a caching issue with the browser.  You could try sending No-Cache headers to see if that fixes it.

Comment: what's in header.php and footer.php?

Comment: header and footer files only have html code.

Answer (score 13):

**Start the session before you start the output buffering.** So, switch the `ob_start()` and `session_start()` calls.

Since session cookies are defined in the headers sent to the browser, and headers are sent to the browser when you start the buffer, you must start the sessions *before* the buffer.

Comment: Sending the HTTP headers to the browser when you ob_start() would defeat the main point of output buffering, why in the world would you say that it does that? Further, even if it did do that, it wouldn't make any difference in this context. Why did a non-sequitur based on a false statement get this many upvotes?

Answer (score 2):

The example you provided should work. Perhaps some kind of session cache is getting in your way. You could try modifying your code as follows:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['invite_errors']) && $_SESSION['invite_errors']) {

    $error = $_SESSION['invite_errors'];
    $_SESSION['invide_errors'] = false;
    unset($_SESSION['invite_errors']);

    // Explicitly write and close the session for good measure
    session_write_close();

}
```

Comment: Using WAMP server, I had to include session_write_close() to delete the session cookie. Nothing else worked.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, PHP sessions aren't worth using and were only designed as a quick and easy solution. $_SESSION behaviour is not always obvious but using sessions in the traditional sense is mostly unavoidable. Issue your own id and token cookies and store session values against these, perhaps in a database.  This also has the benefit of being scalable across servers.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can change the value after echo'ing the error

```
if (isset($_SESSION['invite_error'])) {
   echo $_SESSION['invite_error'];
   $_SESSION['invite_error'] = null;
   unset($_SESSION['invite_error']);
}
```