# unset session variable halts execution

Tags: php, oop, session, unset

I have been going crazy over this piece of code and narrowed it down to the unset function. When I call unset on the session variable, PHP doesn't execute anything beyond that point. Can someone please help?

```
public static function print_session_notification() {

    if( isset( $_SESSION['notification'] )) {
        $session_notification = $_SESSION['notification'];

        $output = '<div class="error">';
        $output .= $_SESSION['notification'];
        $output .= '</div>';

        unset( $_SESSION['notification'] );

        return $output;
    }
}
```

I call print notification::print_session_notification(); from a header include. The header include is called by a function. The $notification object is global in the function that calls the header file.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you posted, and it won't reproduce your error. Try reproducing your error with the smallest amount of code possible. We can't help you with what you've posted.

Comment: Do you have register_globals being 'ON'? http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php#40539 possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025300/problem-unsetting-a-session-variable

Comment: We'll need to see the code or function which calls `print_session_notification()`, at the very least.

Comment: Why are localizing the session value to $session_notification, but not using it? Seems like you can just get rid of that line.

Comment: Sorry Guys I forgot to mention that I call print notification::print_session_notification(); from a header include. The header include is called by a function.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by adding a method to the construct and assigning the session values to public properties. Thanks for your help guys!!!

Answer (score -1):

Please make sure that you set session_start() function on you header and set register_globals to "ON"

For more information read the comments on http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php

Comment: Register Globals has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0