# Unset session variable not working when preventing double submissions

Tags: php, session, csrf, adodb, double-submit-problem

I am trying preventing a user double submitting a form if they click the button twice using the below code.

```
// Check token is present
if (!isset($_POST['token'])) {
    // Token missing
    exit();
}

// Check token matches session value
if ($_POST['token'] != $_SESSION['token']) {
    // Token mismatch
    exit();
}

// Valid submission - Invalidate token
unset($_SESSION['token']);


// Make payment
$result = makePayment(); // cURL request to api
```

The problem is that `unset($_SESSION['token'])` doesn't seem to be working. On the 2nd request, the token is still in the session. I think it's because the session value is not getting cleared before the next submission.

In this resepnse to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1025919/1587851 `session_write_close()` is suggested and I think adding it after my unset is working, but I don't really understand what it does:

```
// Valid submission - Invalidate token
unset($_SESSION['token']);
session_write_close();
```

Two questions:

1. **Is there any problems with this solution?**
2. **Can I still get and set session variables after calling session_write_close()?**

Thanks.

*Might be relevant, I'm using ADOdb to store session data in the database*

Comment: Did you put a "session_start()" at the begin of your page ?

Comment: @mArm.ch yes, it's just not on the above snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do :

```
$_SESSION['token'] = null;
```

Sometimes, the `unset()` is not effective immediatly.